Locking users out for a VERY long time (permanently) in .Net Core
We are migrating an application from Webforms to ASP.Net Core 6 and I'm trying to emulate the bit isLocked in the membership framework by providing a large value for the DefaultLockoutTimeSpan:
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

However, when I do this and trigger a lockout, it just adds like 4 or 5 hours to the current time.  What am I doing wrong here?  Based on information I'm seeing, this should be way, way into the future, no?

What if you add a year? What is the db that holds the data?

@rene ok, but do I have to set that somewhere else manually, like in my login code?  Is it not possible to set it in my program.cs?  I tried using;
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10000);
But this didn't give the expected results, seemed to give the same value as TimeSpan.MaxValue...

In  source code, we could see that DefaultLockoutTimeSpan has default value for 5minutes which looks like this public TimeSpan DefaultLockoutTimeSpan { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); , then could you pls try options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5000); ?

@TinyWang I actually tried this (although I specified .FromDays(10000), and it still just pushes it a few hours into the future

Thanks for your reply, and could you pls try .FromDays(1) which is a little bit small time to see whether it worked or not? I didn't find any document to say it has a limiation, but the TimeSpan definition document mentioned TimeSpan maxSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalDays); would throw an OverflowException at runtime, which might have limitation for the max value... I'm not very sure about it, but it might really have a max value which is not very big.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromdays?view=net-8.0
